# Limiting the total size of samba's vfs_recycle by pruning oldest deleted files first

Tags: samba, disk-usage, limit, vfs

Running SerNet Samba 4.0.9 on CentOS 6.4 serving as an AD DC and fileshare for XP clients.

Added recycler per [the example here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions).

My concern is that the recycle dir will eventually grow large.  [`vfs_recycle`'s docs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_recycle.8.html) mention a parameter for limiting individual file sizes, but what's a best practice to prevent the bin from growing too large?  Cronjob to delete old files when the total is past a certain size?

I found [tmpwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch), but it's only time-based.  What I'd like the system to do is keep files as long as it reasonably can, i.e., without too much space being taken up.  The flip side is that I also don't want it keeping files too long if it means running out of space.  Thus I'm looking for something with roughly this thinking:

1. if bin_size < limit then quit
2. delete oldest file in bin
3. goto 1.

Of course there may be a more efficient algorithm, and it could be tweaked to prefer deleting bigger files unless they're past a certain age so that a big delete doesn't unnecessarily result in the pruning of a bunch of older-but-not-too-old small files.